# Rule for IE. Not working in IE 10

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I specified a rule for all IE versios, but its not working for some reason.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
#topmenu LI.fisrt {
    padding: 5px 5px !important;
    font: 13px/43px sans-serif !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: and you're sure there's no type in there fisrt?

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Support for conditional comments has been removed in Internet Explorer 10 standards and quirks modes for improved interoperability and compliance with HTML5

The idea is that IE10 has much better standards support than older IE versions and there should no longer be any need to conditionally target it.

Comment: Unfortunately this is still not always the case :-/

Comment: :(( yes this is not always the case

Comment: dont know why but on W3C validated HTML5 page (0 errors), my margin on a button in not working. the bug is only on IE.