# Pointer Events on IE 10

Tags: javascript, html, css

IE 10 does [not support conditionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396796/rule-for-ie-not-working-in-ie-10) and we all know that, so regular targeting rules for unsupported css properties arn't an option here. An image to see how IE 10 thinks he is not IE:

[image]

All right, but there are a thing called `pointer-events` that are taking more time to solve than it should. I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie) but no hope in my case. I've a text that is set on top of a deformed `div` button. I applied the `pointer-events:none;` to this `div` text.

```
<div class="btn-text-facebook ">Facebook</div>
<a class="btn-facebook " href="#">
</a>
```

And the CSS:

```
.btn-facebook{
float: left;
background-color: #3B5998;
height: 100%;
padding: 10px;
width: 110px;
transform:skewX(-40deg);
-webkit-transform: skewX(-40deg);
z-index: 1;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px;
border-top-left-radius: 15px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
box-shadow:  inset 0px -1px 1px #999,
            0px 1px 5px 0px rgb(17,17,17);           
    }

.btn-text-facebook{
position: fixed;
top: 17px;
right: 230px;
z-index: 2;
float: left;
color: white;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(250,250,250,0.1); 
pointer-events:none;}
```

My question then is: Is there a solution (js or css) for this kind of problem? Any standart way to deal with it or a good hack.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: When I click the button, it clicks on the text once it's an object with click properties on top. I want it to click only on the button behind it. it works on Chrome, firefoz and safari, but not on IE or Opera as they don't have ponter-events. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Have you looked into possibly using a polyfill? [Hand.js: A polyfill for supporting pointer events in every browser](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/01/16/hand-js-a-polyfill-for-supporting-pointer-events-on-every-browser.aspx). Just a thought...

Comment: @AndréLucas No problem buddy. Glad to help. You may also be interested in [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) combined with [yepnope.js](http://yepnopejs.com/). Using these tools, you would be able to see if the browser supported pointer events. If it does, you can let the browser use the native support. If not, you can use _yepnope.js_ to conditionally load the polyfill. That way you aren't loading and parsing an extra JavaScript file that you don't need in browsers that have native support. This should ensure the user gets the best possible experience across all browsers.